# Filter by a distinguishing field when making publications using meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my publications with meteor.js, I find myself repeating the same style of code and would like a cleaner approach. For example:

I have a `users` collection that has the **distinguishing** field `school`, an identifier that tells me by which school, I should filter what information on the server so that I don't send the wrong school the wrong information. Currently, I

```
Meteor.publish('schoolDirectory', function (schoolId) { 
        return Meteor.users.find({'profile.school': schoolId}});
});
```

Where I take in the `schoolId` on the client, and filter appropriately. I am not sure of the security implications there and have tried switching to a style where I use the authenticated users `object` to determine the school on the server before publishing any more data like so:

```
Meteor.publish('schoolDirectory', function () { 
             var currentUser = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId});
             var schoolId = Schools.findOne({_id: currentUser.profile.school});
            return Meteor.users.find({'profile.school': schoolId}});
    });
```

This has the issue of not being able to publish data for anonymous users, anyone have any suggestions on how to improve the code base to use this distinguishing field globally ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see how you can filter field B (school) that relies on field A (user) when there's no information about field A.

What is the purpose of showing schools to anonymous users?

If we take the scenario of displaying information to anonymous users without any related functionality (read-only stuff), then perhaps you should have another publication which only publishes 'public' properties of the school entities.

Comment: "Should have another publication which only publishes 'public' properties of the school entities". I like that idea. I think I may have to create a publication/subscription for anonymous users.

Comment: i use this pattern extensively. note this doesn't mean you shouldn't protect your meteor methods as well

Comment: Protect my Meteor.method definitions as in running a `check` against passed values being sent to the server

Comment: thats just type checking. you need to authorize the caller, e.g. a change in a user's profile should only be done for that user's request